# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure error in JSP page

Tags: jsp, ssl-certificate, handshake

I have a strange problem with authorized ssl connection. First I have created java class that connects to external server with authorized ssl. I've run this class in command line it works fine, gets desired results from external server. After I've use this class in JSP page. After reboot my tomcat JSP page gets me desired results, too. But after 10-15 requests JSP page gives me this error: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure ". No more desired results in JSP page.

Here is method in java class code:

```
public String TransHttpsAuth(String server, String param, String method, String jksPath, String jksPass)
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jksPath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", jksPass);

        server=server+"/?"+ param;


        URL url = new URL(server);
        HttpsURLConnection httpurlconnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        httpurlconnection.setHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
        httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod(method);
        httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);

        httpurlconnection.connect();
       InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) httpurlconnection.getContent());

       BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
       String line = buff.readLine();
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
       while (line != null) {
           text.append(line + "\n");
           line = buff.readLine();
       }
       System.out.println(text.toString());
       httpurlconnection.disconnect();
        return text.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        return exception+"";
    }
}
```

Calling from JSP page: <%
 fsb fsb = new fsb();
out.println(fsb.TransHttpsAuth("https://ext_server","prameters","GET", "jks_path", "password"));
%>

Tomcat version: 6.0.32

Java version: 1.6.0_21

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the server certificate in your jre and restart tomcat in order to connect using java. Look for InstallCert.java on the web.